# How to properly import components from other files using reagent?

Tags: react-native, clojure, reagent

I want to use a reagent component I've created in another file/namespace, say this.is.the.namespace, and it contains a component defined like so:

```
(defn component-name []
  ; stuff
)
```

In my entry file, I do the following:

```
(ns entry.point.namespace.name
(:require [this.is.the.namespace]
))
```

And when I include [component-name] in a component in the entry file, the component doesn't show. Why might this be?

Comment: Please update your question to include more details of what you've tried and any errors in the console. It should suffice to require the component with something like `(:require [this.is.the.namespace :refer [component-name]])` in your `ns` declaration.

Comment: Complementing @DenisFuenzalida 's answer, you can use either `:refer` as he mentioned, or alias the required ns: `(:require [this.is.the.namespace :as components])` and then using `[components/component-name...]` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

```clj
(ns this.is.the.namespace)

(defn component-name []
  [:p "Hello There"])
```

```clj
(ns entry.point.namespace.name
 (:require [reagent.core :as reagent]
           [this.is.the.namespace :as my-components]))

(reagent/render [my-components/component-name] (js/getElementById "main-div"))
```

Change "main-div" to id of the div that you are rendering into.